# Controllers in a separate project, but when I try to add a view via "right click", it creates a new Views folder within my Controllers project..?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've got my Controllers in its own project, my Models in their own projects, and the Main App in ITS own project, which contains the Views folder.

So when I open up my controller cs file and right click on, say for example, the Details action and choose "Add View", it creates a Views folder within my Controllers project, and adds the view there.  I want it to add the view into the Views folder in my Main App project.  How in the world do I do this?????  Thanks so much in advance for anyone's help and advice!!

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click in your project that has the views to add the view. Views don't care which controller calls them, so there is no reason to click in your controllers project.

Comment: Yeah, I was just trying to keep it simple and let the MVC stuff do what it does automatically- for example, right clicking an action in a controller and choosing "Add View", you're able to specify from the UI whether it's strongly typed, the master page file, etc., and plus it loads the template depending on what kind of view it is (edit, create, list, etc.).  I like having MVC do all that for me versus doing it from scratch.